# Ruby on Rails marketability

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been researching about Ruby on Rails and its marketability today. How does it compare to the other programming languages (like JAVA)? Would it be a really great time to learn it now? Will it be beneficial for me to learn this as my primary programming language?

I just wanted to know the highs and lows for this technology before I dive in and start learning.

Your opinions would be appreciated.

Comment: Rails has a very steep learning curve... But once it starts to click, it's the most fun!... You can very quickly put applications together, and implement famous features such as likes and followers etc... It's a lot easier to learn than JavaScript as it doesn't require parenthesis or semicolons so much, so the code is often easier to read... However you will have about 5 months of just refreshing whilst clenching your fists and pleading that the instance variable is no longer nil... Michael Hartl does an unbelievable job with his rails tutorial book and screencasts

Comment: I did took as stab on reading a few pages of some Ruby/RoR books and was amazed on how quickly you can create something in less than an hour. But how does it compare to Java in terms of marketability and projects? I am searching for Ruby jobs for the past few days but I noticed the scarcity for projects/employers that seek Ruby developers. (esp in my country Philippines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the programming language is Ruby. Ruby on Rails is an awesome framework for fast, efficient building of web applications.

Ruby is an interpreted language in opposition to Java or C#, which are compiled.
With Ruby there's no need for type definition or type casting, no semicolons at the end of the line, no parentheses for method invocations, operators overload, getters/setters automatically available for all instance variables and many, many more. (copied from [here](http://a-developer-life.blogspot.de/2013/03/ruby-vs-java.html))

I think that the learning curve with ruby is very steep.

But, after all, all the above is just an opinion ... my opinion. And you're question "Would it be a really great time to learn it now?" is answered by the pragmatic programmers: Learn a new programming language every year. So, why not starting learn Ruby now?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Im trying to choose between J2EE and RoR as my first language, im thinking which technology would beneficial in terms of marketability.